# Link errors during Static linking of OCCI/ OCI programs in Oracle 12c

Tags: static-linking, oracle-call-interface, oracle12c, occi

I am trying to develop statically linked OCi/OCCI application and I am getting lots of undefined errors like following.

Can somebody tell me which .a libs to be included at link line.

Thanks.

*/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxxmlidc.o): In function `lxXmlIdConv':
lxxmlidc.c:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to`lxuCvtToCtx'
lxxmlidc.c:(.text+0x23f): undefined reference to `lxu4TstClass'
lxxmlidc.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to`lxu4TstClass'
lxxmlidc.c:(.text+0x386): undefined reference to `lxu4TstClass'
lxxmlidc.c:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to`lxu4TstClass'
lxxmlidc.c:(.text+0x3be): undefined reference to `lxu4TstClass'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxxmlidc.o):lxxmlidc.c:(.text+0x7d4): more undefined references to`lxu4TstClass' follow
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxuca.o): In function `lxucaFindLastNonCombiningChar':
lxuca.c:(.text+0xc82): undefined reference to`lxu4GCombiningClass'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxuca.o): In function `lxucaFindTrimPosition':
lxuca.c:(.text+0xfd6): undefined reference to`lxuCvtToCtx'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxuca.o): In function `lxucaGetKey':
lxuca.c:(text.hot+0xb2c): undefined reference to`lxuComposition'
lxuca.c:(text.hot+0xe06): undefined reference to `lxu4GCombiningClass'
lxuca.c:(text.hot+0xeaa): undefined reference to`lxu4GCombiningClass'
lxuca.c:(text.hot+0x112b): undefined reference to `lxu4GCombiningClass'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxuca.o): In function`lxucaConvertAndDecompose':
lxuca.c:(text.hot+0x181a): undefined reference to `lxuDecomposition'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxuca.o): In function`lxucaGetImplicitWeightBase':
lxuca.c:(text.hot+0x1b16): undefined reference to `lxu4GBlock'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxpisac.o): In function`lxpIsACollationElement':
lxpisac.c:(.text+0x2fc): undefined reference to `lxuCvtToCtx'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libnls12.a(lxpisac.o): In function`lxpNumOfUc4CollationElem':
lxpisac.c:(.text+0x753): undefined reference to `lxuCvtToCtx'
lxpisac.c:(.text+0x91a): undefined reference to`lxuComposition'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libcore12.a(lrmini.o): In function `lrminiu':
lrmini.c:(.text+0x5b6): undefined reference to`lxuCvtToCtx'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libcore12.a(lrmpu.o): In function `lrmpu16to8':
lrmpu.c:(text.unlikely+0x57): undefined reference to`lxuStrLen'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libcore12.a(lsf.o): In function `lsfiniu':
lsf.c:(.text+0x551): undefined reference to`lxuCvtToCtx'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libcore12.a(lsfu.o): In function `lsfu16to8':
lsfu.c:(text.unlikely+0x65): undefined reference to`lxuStrLen'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libcore12.a(lrmckv.o): In function `lrmckv':
lrmckv.c:(.text+0x54f): undefined reference to`lxuCmpBinStr'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libcore12.a(lrmpatk.o): In function `lrmpatk':
lrmpatk.c:(text.unlikely+0x2f1): undefined reference to`lxuCmpBinStr'
/u01/home/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/lib/libcore12.a(lrmcvv.o): In function `lrmcvv':
lrmcvv.c:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to`lxuCmpBinStr'*

Comment: I did this once many years ago. aside the library liclntsh.so there is also a library libclntst.a (sh-shared, st-static). Look at the relink script - this one might generate the static version of the library. Also I recall I needed static version of some libs shipped with Intel's ICC compiler(Oracle does not use gcc). Simply write a script that uses `nm` and try to find missing symbols in all `.a` `.o` files shipped with Oracle installation. What command you use to link your app?

Comment: g++. Is libclntst.a static equivalent of libclntsh.so ?

Comment: I used to be. As I remember on ver. 8i/9i. See post installation tasks: http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10811_05/ch4.htm. But even if I used this library I had to find some symbols from ICC compiler. Something like __fast_memcpy. I think even gcc has its libgcc library which contains necessary runtime functions.

Comment: I am using nm and finding the .a files to include at link line. Does ordering of those files on Link line matters ? If so what should be the ordering ?

Comment: I'm not sure. ld should complain about implicitly defined symbols (but I'm not sure about weak-symbols). PS: I do not have an access to any Linux box ATM.

Comment: Thanks I have used nm command for all the symbols on all Oracle libraries and included them in link line. After trying some permutations and combinations it got linked

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I have used nm command for all the symbols on all Oracle libraries and included them in link line. After trying some permutations and combinations it got linked

Comment: you should publish what you came up with for the next poor sob that finds themselvs in the same situation.

Comment: For each symbol not found error ...goto lib dir under Oracle ... use nm command to find the .a file in which the symbol exists and and that file to link line.